# Evalute $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x^4}}{8+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Having a hard time with this. So far I have:

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^2)}}{8+x^2} = \frac{x\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{8+x^2}$$

Comment: you should notice that $\frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^2)}}{8+x^2} = \frac{-x\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{8+x^2}$

Comment: A correction on the original question: Note that $$ \frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^2)}}{8+x^2} = \frac{|x|\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{8+x^2}$$
So whether you approach from $\pm\infty$ the limit is the same.

Comment: It's almost a shame that the function in question has even symmetry, so that it suffices to find the limit in the positive infinite direction, yielding a single horizontal asymptote for the function.  Were the polynomial in the denominator _odd_ , making the function _odd_ as well, we would have the opportunity to illustrate "splitting" of the horizontal asymptote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean
$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x^4}}{8+x^2}$.

Since $x^2$ and $x^4$ are positive,
the limit is the same for
$x \to \infty$ and
$x \to -\infty$.

You can take your last step
further and write

$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x^4}}{8+x^2}
&= \frac{x\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{8+x^2}\\
&= \frac{x^2\sqrt{1/x^2+4}}{x^2(1+8/x^2)}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{1/x^2+4}}{1+8/x^2}\\
\end{align}
$

As $x \to \pm \infty$,
$\sqrt{1/x^2+4} \to \sqrt{4} = 2$
and
$1+8/x^2 \to 1$,
so I get
$\frac{2}{1} = 1$.

Comment: $$\dfrac 2 1=1$$

Hmm... =)

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$ \lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^2)}}{8+x^2} =\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^2)}}{8+x^2} = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{x^2}+4)}}{\frac{8}{x^2}+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Other hint: What does $4x^2 + 1$ as x goes to infinity (or -infinity, as another user noted - it gives the same result)

Comment: Would you rephrase that?

Comment: I don't see the need to...what is unclear?

Comment: "What does $4x^2+1$ as x goes to infinity"?

Comment: Sorry; what does the square root of $4x^2 + 1$ approach as x goes to infinity?

Comment: What you want to say is that $$\sqrt{4x^2+1}$$ behaves just like $2x$ has $x$ goes to infinity, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - Thank you

Comment: No problem. ${}{}{}$

Comment: How is that so? 4x^2 + 1 as x goes to infinity is infinity. Correct? Square root of infinity is?

Comment: What I meant to say is how does the square root of $4x^2 + 1$ as x goes to infinity behave? Clearly the 1 does not have any say in the matter, the limit approaches 2x. Hope that helps

Comment: Need help in understanding that. I don't see it. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Suppose you pick out some large number and plug it in to the square root of $4x^2 + 1$. Does this give you the same result, or very close to, the square root of $4x^2$? Thus, instead of using $4x^2 + 1$, it is safe to say $4x^2$ will do quite nicely here. Thus the limit will turn out to be 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a match-in-heaven for high-school level Non-Standard Analysis (see [Keisler textbook](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html)).
Since $x$  goes to infinity, we can replace it by the "larger than any real number" $H = \frac {1}{\epsilon} $ where $\epsilon$ is the infinitesimal (smallest than any real number), and dispense with the $\lim$ altogether.

So we can write

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^2)}}{8+x^2} = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{8+x^2} = \frac {H\sqrt{1+4H^2}}{8+H^2}$$

Note that we continue raising $H$ to powers as though it was a number. To by-pass the square-root, consider the square root of the expression squared:

$$\sqrt {\left(\frac {H\sqrt{1+4H^2}}{8+H^2}\right)^2} = \sqrt {\frac {H^2(1+4H^2)}{64+16H^2 + H^4}} = \sqrt {\frac {H^2+4H^4}{64+16H^2 + H^4}}$$

Take out $H^4$ as common factor,

$$= \sqrt {\frac {H^4(\frac {1}{H^2}+4)}{H^4(\frac {64}{H^4}+\frac {16}{H^2} + 1)}}$$

The term $H^4$ simplifies, and the terms $\frac {1}{H^2}$, $\frac {64}{H^4}$, $\frac {16}{H^2}$ all equal zero. So we ar left with

$$= \sqrt {\frac 41} = 2$$

Who said that you cannot treat infinity as a number? [Abraham Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Robinson) formalized it once and for ... the time being.